# ubuntu 18.04: Display unclaimed, video card driver issue - cannot login - how to resolve?

Tags: display, snap, gpu-driver

All previous queries aside as they seem independent from the current issue after a complete reinstallation - (without a partition other than for the OS itself)

Now I can login only at the aid of recovery mode. From my google search, I concluded the reason is due to video card driver.

The command `sudo lshw` returns `display: UNCLAIMED`. Since I don't know how to copy from the terminal screen (...) I will type under here:

```
description: 3D controller
product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memoery:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
```

I have followed the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to download the adequate software of whatever driver needed for functioning. This does not fix the situation though.

Because now it returns `snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it`. I am not certain if this has much to do with my situation, as the circumstance in the [link](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-service-doesnt-start/319) is not related to login issue.

Either way, has anyone got a piece of experience/knowledge to share ?

Comment: previous queries -> of mine. If you read, you will see that I have searched similar problems and have reached the understanding the example link provides.

Comment: Will upload if that helps.. if you would care to explain, would help me understand the source of the problem. At the moment just removing `snapd` so as to reinstall clean again. `apport` package also causes issue in `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which I believed would solve most of my problems.

Comment: `sudo` elevates your privileges; `dpkg` deals with packages (already on your system) -- it cannot download as you state in your question.  using `dpkg --configure -a` is used to continue configuring packages already on your system (usually because the install was interrupted for some reason).  If you are using a term & can't copy/paste; I'd suggest `ssh`ing into the box from a location you can, and copy/paste on that box. Maybe helpful are https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353796 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377560  (you didn't even tell us your version of Ubuntu)

Comment: right. while i knew `sudo` was for, guess i misunderstood the use of `dpkg` - Thx. Think I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` but not sure I downloaded a new install afterwards. In the meantime, my laptop stopped turning on for some reason. It makes the noise 'beep' and the keyboard light is on, but the screen remains black. So I'd have to address this first